# Issue running python fastmask example

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to run the example in https://github.com/voidrank/FastMask, specifically the Image Demo. After cloning and building the repository, I run the following command:

```
python image_demo.py 0 fm-res39 input.jpg --init_weights=fm-res39_final_params.caffemodel
```

However, I end up getting the following error:

```
Net('fastmask/models/fm-res39.test.prototxt', 1, weights='fastmask/params/fm-res39_final_params.caffemodel')
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:245] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 3629:24: Message type "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "sliding_window_param".
F1007 02:15:28.920272 13342 upgrade_proto.cpp:88] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file: fastmask/models/fm-res39.test.prototxt
```

It seems like there is an issue with the "sliding_window_parameter" but I'm not sure how to deal with it. Any ideas?